# Where does default PHP locale come from?

Tags: php, bash, debian

I stumbled over a locale pitfall in PHP-CLI v7.3 on a GNU/Linux (Debian 10 Buster) server.

```sh
php -v
PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2021 16:31:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-1~deb10u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

All float and/or double numbers are echo′ed with a decimal comma. But I want it to be printed with a decimal dot, as I would expect it—despite the fact that my Bash is set to `de_DE.UTF-8`.

**Pitfall example**

```php
<?php
$f = 4.2;
echo $f, PHP_EOL;
var_dump($f);
```

**Pitfall output**

```sh
php float.php 
4,2
float(4,2)
```

**Solution 1**

Run the script with overridden environment `LC_NUMERIC` set to `C` variable.

```sh
LC_NUMERIC=C php float.php 
4.2
float(4.2)
```

**Solution 2**

Set expected locale in the code (output identical to solution 1).

```php
<?php
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
$f = 4.2;
echo $f, PHP_EOL;
var_dump($f);
```

**My question is:** *Why is PHP′s locale set to `de_DE.UTF-8` and where does it come from?*

**Where I looked**

```sh
grep -Prin '^[^;#]*(locale|lc|lang|intl)' /etc/default/ /etc/environment* /etc/php/
/etc/default/locale:2:LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
/etc/php/7.0/phpdbg/php.ini:963:[intl]
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini.ucf-dist:1002:[intl]
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini:1002:[intl]
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini:1002:[intl]
/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/intl.ini:3:extension=intl.so
/etc/php/7.3/phpdbg/php.ini:1002:[intl]
```

```sh
php -i | grep intl.default_locale
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
```

```php
<?php
echo locale_get_default();      # => en_US
echo setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 0);  # => de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: Its explained on [this page of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php)

Comment: Basically from `intl.default_locale` in the `php.ini` if it is set, or from the underlying OS if it is not

Comment: Unfortunately, the `intl.default_locale` is not set. And `locale_get_default()` returns `en_US`. So, this does not apply to my pitfall.